# DataBinding in ListView: Not all columns get updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In a WPF application, I have a listview defined like that:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOperationMode.Steps}">
 <ListView.View>
  <GridView>
   <GridViewColumn Header="Step" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
   <GridViewColumn Header="Elapsed Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ElapsedTime}"/>
   <GridViewColumn Header="State" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource EnumToDescriptionConverter}}"/>
  </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The viewmodel, I have this Code:

```
private EventHandler stateChangedHandler;
private OperationMode _selectedOperationMode;
public OperationMode SelectedOperationMode
{
 get
 {
  return _selectedOperationMode;
 }
 set
 {
  _selectedOperationMode?.Steps.ForEach(step => step.StateChanged -= stateChangedHandler);
  _selectedOperationMode = value;
  _selectedOperationMode.Steps.ForEach(step => step.StateChanged += stateChangedHandler);
  StartButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
  RaisePropertyChanged();
  }
 }
```

In the constructor of the viewmodel, I instantiate the stateChangedHandler as follows:

```
stateChangedHandler = (s, e) => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOperationMode));
```

In the OperationMode class, Steps is a List<Step>. Step is an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Step
{
    private DateTime? startTime, endTime;

    public abstract string DisplayText { get; }

    public event EventHandler StateChanged;

    private StepState _state = StepState.NotExecuted;
    public StepState State
    {
        get
        {
            return _state;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if(_state != value)
            {
                _state = value;
                StateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan? ElapsedTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (startTime == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return (endTime ?? DateTime.Now) - startTime;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        State = StepState.Executing;
        StepState result = ExecuteInternal();
        endTime = DateTime.Now;
        State = result;
    }

    protected abstract State ExecuteInternal();
}
```

The following should happen: A loop iterates over the list of steps and executes every step. During that, the State property of each step changes. Hence the `StateChanged` event is invoked. This will lead to `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOperationMode))` to be called, which invokes the `PropertyChanged` event from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I expect that in the listview, both the column for state and the column for the elapsed time get updated. For an unknown reason, only the state column gets updated. The column for the elapsed time does *not* get updated. I checked with the debugger that only the getter of the State property is called after calling `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOperationMode))`, but not the getter of the `ElapsedTime` property. The binding of the `ElapsedTime` column works, which I checked by changing the getter of `ElapsedTime` in the Step class that it just returns some default value (like `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)`).

Does anybody see my mistake?

Comment: What exactly is `RaisePropertyChanged()` doing? Does it use the `CallerMemberName` attribute, or does it fire the PropertyChanged event with a null or empty property name?

Comment: It does the following: public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }

Comment: Without passing an argument value, i.e. an actual `propertyName`? How is it supposed to work at all if you do not explicitly fire a PropertyChanged event for the `ElapsedTime` property, or a `null` property name to notify about a change of *all*  properties?

Comment: @SomeBody: Why don't you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event in the `Step` class and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in each of the databound properties?

Comment: @mm8: Good Question. I always assumed that only the DataContext can invoke the PropertyChanged event. After implementing INotifyPropertyChanged also in the step class, it works very well. For curiosity, it just leaves the question, why the above code could update the State column, but not the ElapsedTime column on the UI.

Comment: @SomeBody: I am note sure without being able to run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event in the `Step` class and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in each of the databound properties whenever you want to refresh the UI.